# Azure Functions Runtime is unreachable - Works published locally - Fails on CI/CD Deployment (Q&A)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Function (not in a container).

When I publish it to Azure locally, it's fine.

When I publish it from Azure Devops, the deployment succeeds, but the Function wont run. Error 'Azure functions runtime is unreachable':

[image]

I've tried looking in the Log Stream, but this gives the error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly '{myAppName},
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I've looked at documents such as this [troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-recover-storage-account), but that's not fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When publishing locally, the standard publish format is 'Portable'. This is not precompiled, so the Functions App will compile it when starting up the app.

[image]

However, when publishing from CI/CD, I was compiling as part of the publish, using the following command:

```
dotnet publish projectName --framework $framework -r win-x64 -c Release
```

Obviously, this is an x64 build.

I checked the App Service Configuration, and it was set to x86.

Changing it to x64 fixed the problem when deploying from DevOps.

[image]

I then also changed the local publish to x64, just to save compile time on startup.