# Azure function runtime unreachable using app settings

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have an azure function app ( time trigger functions ) which is giving "Azure Function runtime is unreachable" error. We are using appsetting.json in place of local.host.json and the variables are configured in devops pipeline. I can see that the variables gets updated in azure function app files, However function is not executing yet it shows some memory consumption every 3o mins. Please  share your suggestions to fix this. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I Know,
`Azure Functions Runtime is unreachable` comes if the function app is blocked by firewall or storage account configuration is incorrect in the Connection String.

I found few solved issues in the SO for similar errors in the context of Azure Functions deployed through Azure DevOps Pipelines where user @*JsAndDotNet* solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71050589/16630138) the above error by correcting the Platform value in Configuration menu of deployed Azure Function App in the portal.

Another user @*DelliganeshSevanesan* solved this error in the Context of Azure Functions Deployment using IDEs [70934637](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70934637/16630138) where multiple reasons are given as a check to this error along with the resolutions.

Also, I have observed we need to add Azure Function App Configuration Settings in the Pipeline with the form of Key-Value Pair, which is also known as **transformation of the local.settings.json of Azure Function App to the Azure CI/CD Pipelines**.  For this, I have found the practical workarounds given by @*VijayanathViswanathan* and @*Sajid* in these SO Issue [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61598490) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54606696).